# How Can I use key the change the value of a specific multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm facing an issue in a multi dimensional array. I need to change the quantity of a specific product set in session if both ID and variants of the selection are the same of one of session product, and increment by 1 this product.

the product I'm posting `$newproduct`

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [title] => Vewlix 1080p (red and white)
    [image] => amazing-modern-villa-Freshome-02.jpg
    [variants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [option_name] => Panel 2 players (+50 euros)
                    [option_price] => 50.00
                )

        )

    [quantity] => 1
    [unit_price] => 1950.00
    [price] => 2000
)
```

Here is my `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Vewlix 1080p (red and white)
            [image] => amazing-modern-villa-Freshome-02.jpg
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [option_name] => Panel 1 player
                            [option_price] => 0.00
                        )

                )

            [quantity] => 2
            [unit_price] => 1950.00
            [price] => 1950
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Vewlix 1080p (red and white)
            [image] => amazing-modern-villa-Freshome-02.jpg
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [option_name] => Panel 2 players (+50 euros)
                            [option_price] => 50.00
                        )

                )

            [quantity] => 1
            [unit_price] => 1950.00
            [price] => 2000
        )

    )
```

The code:

```
$products_in_cart = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "id");
$key = array_search($newproduct["id"], $products_in_cart);

if ($key !== false) {
    $variants_in_cart = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]["variants"], "id");
    $new_variants = array_column($newproduct["variants"], "id");
    sort($variants_in_cart);
    sort($new_variants);

    if (count(array_diff($variants_in_cart, $new_variants)) === 0) {
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]["quantity"] += 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $newproduct;
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $newproduct;
}
```

For now I have the ID and variants comparaison working, but when similiar product is posted, instead of incrementing only the specific product with same id/variants, it increments all products quantities of my session by +1.

How can I add +1 only to the product with exact same ID / variants only ? I think my [$key] doesn't work, as it should be the filter to only increment the proper product quantity

Comment: What is `$newproduct`? Just another array the same as in the session?

Comment: `$newproduct` is what I'm pushing in my `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']` if IDs are differents, or if IDs are the same, but variants of my product differents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop over the array like that. Start by getting a list of the IDs in the shopping cart already. If there's a match, pull the key from that list,  check the variants, and increment. Otherwise, just add it.

```
<?php
$_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = json_decode('[{"id": 2, "quantity": 1, "variants": [{"option_id": 3}, {"option_id": 9}]}, {"id": 1, "quantity": 1, "variants": [{"option_id": 5}]}]', true);
$newproduct = json_decode('{"id": 2, "variants": [{"option_id": 3}, {"option_id": 9}]}', true);

$products_in_cart = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "id");
$key = array_search($newproduct["id"], $products_in_cart);

if ($key !== false) {
    $variants_in_cart = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]["variants"], "option_id");
    $new_variants = array_column($newproduct["variants"], "option_id");
    sort($variants_in_cart);
    sort($new_variants);
    if (count(array_diff($variants_in_cart, $new_variants)) === 0) {
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]["quantity"] += 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $newproduct;
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $newproduct;
}

var_dump($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    'id' =>
    int(2)
    'quantity' =>
    int(2)
    'variants' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      array(1) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      array(1) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    'id' =>
    int(1)
    'quantity' =>
    int(1)
    'variants' =>
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      array(1) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, if I'm not playing with the variants, it works. But how Can I do to check the different variants in each product, and only add +1 only if the ID is the same (that we have now) but also variants are the same ?

Add push `$newproduct` if one of both are different

Comment: You add a similar check for that array, in the same code block where the increment is.

Comment: Almost working. I created this arrays `$variants_diff = array_map('unserialize', array_diff(array_map('serialize', $variants_choices), array_map('serialize', $shopping_variants)));` with a foreach before to compare variants. And it works. I have or an empty array() if variants are similar, or the return changes in a variable. All work, except that if 2 products with same ID but different variants, are found, it +1 the first one (once again I don't know why the [$key] seems to not work.

Code in my topic updated

Comment: I don't know, my code looks at the variants and works in both cases. Perhaps you should use it.

Comment: I did, with `$products_variants_in_cart = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "variants");
     $result = array_search($newproduct['variants'], $products_variants_in_cart);` But can't get it work

Comment: Ok, I changed "variant_id" by "option_name" but fit with my case. I add a first product with same id/variant as the first I created, it works and add +1. I add a second product with different variants, it creates a new one. But If I add a product with same variants has the second one, it creates a new product, instead of adding +1 to the second product. So I have 2 products created with same id/variants: https://i.imgur.com/qMOMJTH.png

Comment: miken32, I updated the topic for a much clearer situation. It's supposed with this `$newproduct` and your code to add "+1" to the second product in the shopping cart. Instead of this it creates a 3rd product with similar ID/VARIANTS as the second one. I tried again all this afternoon with no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not a big problem. You might just want to add a correct `if` to your codes so that to do the `++` for that one new item, that you might get.

I'm not so sure about some of your variables. But, my guesswork is that, you just might need an `if` before your `array_push`, maybe something similar to this:

```
        if ((int) $newproduct['id'] == (int) $value["id"]) {
            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'] = (int) $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'] + 1;
        }
```

and your problem would be solved, if you add a correct `if`, so that not to add the `++` to all `$value`s. This one also might work:

```
        if ((int) $newproduct['id'] == (int) $value["id"]) {
            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'] = (int) $value['quantity'] + 1;
        }
```

---

```
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array
    (
    "0" => array
    (
        "id" => "2",
        "title" => "Vewlix 1080p (red and white)",
        "image" => "amazing-modern-villa-Freshome-02.jpg",
        "variants" => array
        (
            "0" => array
            (
                "option_id" => "1",
                "option_name" => "Panel 1 player",
                "option_price" => "0.00",
            ),

        ),

        "quantity" => "1",
        "unit_price" => "1950.00",
        "price" => "1950",
    ),

    "1" => array
    (
        "id" => "2",
        "title" => "Vewlix 1080p (red and white)",
        "image" => "amazing-modern-villa-Freshome-02.jpg",
        "variants" => array
        (
            "0" => array
            (
                "option_id" => "1",
                "option_name" => "Panel 2 players (+50 euros)",
                "option_price" => "50.00",
            ),

        ),

        "quantity" => "1",
        "unit_price" => "1950.00",
        "price" => "2000",
    ),

);

foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($newproduct['id'], $shopping_ids) && empty($variants_diff)) {
        if ((int) $newproduct['id'] == (int) $value["id"]) {
            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'] = (int) $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'] + 1;
        }
    } else {
        array_push($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], $newproduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Emma! Same behavior. It adds +1 quantity to all products in my shopping cart